# weird rendering of / event handling on transformed svg children in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-transforms

So, I have an SVG overlay which has a polygon drag handles for resizing a box around areas of a scalable image.  In Chrome, everything is working swimmingly, but in Firefox is all falls apart in ways that are hard to describe.

Specifically, in Firefox (tested in 54 and 57), the polygon and drag-handles visibly render in the right place, but are not accessible by pointer events.  I have played around with the `pointer-events` CSS rule, but that doesn't appear to be an issue (or at least not the obvious, primary issue).

I *am* able to interact with the drag handles in Firefox if I increase the `r` value of the drag handles or the stroke-width beyond a certain threshold.

I have [created a codepen](https://codepen.io/dehuszar/pen/RjmQqK?editors=1001#0) demonstrating the behavior.

In this example I have increased the size of the top-left, center-left, and bottom-left (or their stroke).  The top and center left handles will demonstrate a hover effect, whereas the bottom-left does not.  If I bumped the bottom left r up a notch, it will be hoverable.  The rest of the handles are not hoverable in FireFox.  There is also a rotate-handle which is not as large as the others, but is hoverable anyway.  Again, everything works great in Chrome.

What's even weirder is that the *hoverable/eventable* space is usually not right over the rendered element.  It's often, a little above, below, or off to the side.  For instance, the hoverable space over the top left handle is a little further up and to the left of the handle.

I thought initially this might have to do with Firefox's issues around transform-origin, but after a fair amount of tinkering, I'm not sure it's relevant here; especially with the object visually rendering exactly where it's supposed to.

Totally stumped.

Comment: If I was a betting man, I would bet on rounding errors. You have defined a radius of 0.0004 and then scale everything by 3692. Resolve the scaling, and try again.

Comment: @ccprog Thanks for responding.  When you say "resolve the scaling", you mean just trimming the decimal places on the scale transform?  I've updated the pen to reflect that, but am still seeing the eventable space offset from the visual rendering by what appears to be the same amount.

Comment: No, what I meant was applying the transforms to the group members, so that path and positioning data are expressed in viewport coordinates, as in `(x', y') = matrix × (x, y)`. Do not forget to scale stroke-width, also.

Comment: @ccprog Interesting.  Well, I moved the transform statements to the group members and there is _some_ shift in where the eventable space lines up with the rendered objects, but it's still not right.  Do you think an actual matrix transform would yield different results than using the translate, scale, and rotate transform statements in sequence?

[Here's a link](https://codepen.io/dehuszar/pen/BJBVgz?editors=1111) to the forked pen with those changes.

Comment: My suggestion was to test just that. I said "rounding error", which means I suspect that Firefox might have a bug when computing the final screen coordinates from point data and transformations. You can only test that if you compute those numbers yourself and compare what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else seeing this at a later date, @ccprog was definitely on the right track. After discussing with Mozilla support, they indicated that large decimal values were above C++ precision levels, and that instead of scaling on the parent and letting the scale trickle down, just applying the scale directly to the group members fixed the rendering issue in Firefox.